# How can I create a column containing the date and time of a whole year in a dataset in R?

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataset of 61,368 rows with data from 2015 to 2021, each row is one hour of one day of the year.
Here is an example of the table

| Site_1 | Site_2 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2015 |
| 3 | 9 | 2015 |
| 2 | 7 | 2015 |
| 5 | 3 | 2015 |
| 0 | 6 | 2015 |

The above data corresponds to the first 5 records of January 1, 2015 (from 00:00 to 04:00). And so the data continues until 23:00 on December 31, 2021.

How can I create a column, containing a date in dmy_hm format, preferably using tidyverse?

What I want is something like the following table

| Site_1 | Site_2 | Year | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2015 | 01-01-2015 00:00 |
| 3 | 9 | 2015 | 01-01-2015 01:00 |
| 2 | 7 | 2015 | 01-01-2015 02:00 |
| 5 | 3 | 2015 | 01-01-2015 03:00 |
| 0 | 6 | 2015 | 01-01-2015 04:00 |

I have tried to use the rep() function but have not been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `seq()`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(date = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), 
    by = "1 hour", 
    length.out = n()
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Site_1 Site_2  Year date               
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1      1      5  2015 2015-01-01 00:00:00
2      3      9  2015 2015-01-01 01:00:00
3      2      7  2015 2015-01-01 02:00:00
4      5      3  2015 2015-01-01 03:00:00
5      0      6  2015 2015-01-01 04:00:00
```

You say you want the date "in dmy_hm format," but dates and datetimes in R don’t have a modifiable print format. If you really want the values displayed that way, you can convert to a formatted character using `strftime()` or `format()`:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(date = strftime(
     seq(
       as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), 
       by = "1 hour", 
       length.out = n()
    ),
    "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Site_1 Site_2  Year date          
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
1      1      5  2015 01/01/15 00:00
2      3      9  2015 01/01/15 01:00
3      2      7  2015 01/01/15 02:00
4      5      3  2015 01/01/15 03:00
5      0      6  2015 01/01/15 04:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the sequence of dates using

```
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-15 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-12-31 23:00:00"), by="hour")
```

And then `cbind` it to your dataframe

`new_data <- cbind(df, dates)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
The above answers helped me a lot to solve my problem, I used the basic ideas from those answers and put it together with the lubridate package :)

```
library("lubridate")    
dates <- seq(ymd_hm("2015-1-1 0:00"),
                       ymd_hm("2021-12-31 23:00"),
                       by = "hour") %>% as.data.frame()
```